# Can't POST data using JavaScript fetch API

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch

I'm trying to `POST` data to my server using the `fetch` API and every time I do I end up with an empty body.

As far as I can tell from the [`fetch` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), to post data you need to pass an object with a method key set to "POST" and a body key with a string or `FormData` object (or some others).

Here's a simple example that is just not working as I would expect:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("test", "woohoo");
formData.append("foo", "bar")
// prints out contents of formData to show that it has contents!
formData.forEach(function(key, value) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
});

fetch("/fetch", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  // Logs empty object
  console.log(json);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I also have an express server on the back of this that logs the request body and echoes it in the response.

```
app.post("/fetch", function(req, res) {
  // Logs empty object :(
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

I add the `formData` as the body of the `fetch` request, but nothing ever seems to go through.

[Please find my test files in this gist here](https://gist.github.com/philnash/4ce0c0b10ef510f4dc440c3f9d5a24d6) and help!

Comment: I believe you're missing `throw new TennisBall()`, which is all you need for fetch. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your node server isn't understanding mulitpart forms correctly (which is what `FormData`) will send by default.

You can use [node-muliparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) on your server you can read the form easily without touching the frontend code.

Something like:

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var app = express();

app.post("/fetch", function(req, res) {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log(fields);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fields));
  });
});
```

in your `index.js` will show you it working correctly. There might be a way to make this work with `body-parser` but I don't know how myself.